# Uploaded AAB. have no permission but, try to change target error : you must remove the request for location permission

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-console

Uploaded AAb. have no permission but, when I try to change target under 13 Error show : you must remove the request for location permission.

[Image that show Abb have No Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW7eX.png)

[Error Show On Change Age Rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPUaW.png)

Comment: please add the screenshot of the Error also. What extra packages added in your unity project ?

Comment: I Also Uploaded An empty project and try to change age target but the issue is same external sdk is only Admob, unity Ads.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, Admob includes the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And multiple other location-required permissions, to locate ad types and language.

So if you want to upload it for <13, you should remove AdMob.

Comment: I am using Admob in many other Apps this issue not face until know with Admob.

Comment: @MehreenIrfan and all the other Apps are < 13? Anyway, try to remove the Admob and check if it works

Comment: yes all the other App < 13
And I Also try to Upload a Blank AAb. which have not a single line of code but the issue is same.

Comment: @MehreenIrfan can you paste on your question your AndroidManifest.xml pls?

Comment: @MehreenIrfan couple of things: 1-Paste it on your question, not in comments pls (and correctly formatted) 2-This doesn't look like your final Unity project AndroidManifest, try to open your apk/aab on AndroidStudio and extract the final AndroidManifest (which is the one with all the previously merged Manifest)